Spin importance for the prob. density and norm conservation
In our class, we discussed about time-dependent quantum systems.
$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt}|\psi(t)\rangle=H(t)|\psi(t)\rangle$
Initial conditions: $|\psi(t_0)\rangle$ is known.
Therefore we can determine $|\psi(t)\rangle$ for any moment in time.
Additionally we prove the conservation of:
1.Norm
2.Probability
Norm conservation:
$\frac{d}{dt}\langle\psi(t)|\psi(t)\rangle=0$
Probability conservation:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\rho(\vec r,t)+\vec\nabla\vec J(\vec r,t)=0$ (continuity equation)
What I found odd was that in both instances, where we had to showcase the conservation, we considered a system without spin, i.e particle without spin exposed to some potential $V(\vec r,t)$.
How would the consideration of spin affect the conservations of both, the norm and probability ?
